# Error saving pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Expected version number after ">=" in ">=2-0-0-dev <3.0.0", got "2-0-0-dev <3.0.0"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

My **pubspec.yaml** file looks like this:

```
name: myproject_functions
description: My Project functions
version: 0.0.1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  firebase_functions_interop: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.9.0
  build_node_compilers: ^0.2.4
```

I get the following output error when I save it:

```
[functions] dart pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 14, column 8 of /Users/myname/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/built_collection-4.2.2/pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Expected version number after ">=" in ">=2-0-0-dev <3.0.0", got "2-0-0-dev <3.0.0".
   ╷
14 │   sdk: '>=2-0-0-dev <3.0.0'
   │        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
exit code 65
```

My Dart SDK verion is `Dart SDK version: 2.16.1 (stable) (Tue Feb 8 12:02:33 2022 +0100) on "macos_x64"`

I've tried changing the SDK upper and lower bounds.

I'm confused why the error is referring to **line 14** when the **pubspec.yaml** file only has 13 lines. Also, where is it picking up the `">+2-0-0-dev"` ? This isn't anywhere in the **pubspec.yaml** file I'm saving.

Comment: I noticed that you don't have flutter in your dependencies. [Flutter and the pubspec file](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec). Could you add it and try to pubget once again?

Comment: Try upgrading your packages using terminal. "flutter pub upgrade"

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `/Users/myname/.pub-cache/` and try again. It caches some different version of package when you have multiple flutter versions or installed different versions of flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Delete pubspec.lock
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Run `flutter pub get`