# Not able to add mocktail to my flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to add mocktail from pub.dev into pubspec.yaml but not able to add it after updating to flutter 3.3.2. I tried changing the environment parameter to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter

    flutter_lints:
    flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
    integration_test:
      sdk: flutter
    mocktail:
```

but the problem did not get solved.

```
Error on line 1, column 1 of ..\..\flutter_windows_v1.12.13Base\flutter\.pub-
cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\.cache\mocktail-versions.json: Invalid version constraint:
Expected version number after ">=" in ">=2.12-0-0 <3.0.0", got "2.12-0-0 <3.0.0".

pub get failed (65; Error on line 1, column 1 of 
..\..\flutter_windows_v1.12.13Base\flutter\.pub-
cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\.cache\mocktail-versions.json: Invalid version constraint:
 Expected version number after ">=" in ">=2.12-0-0 <3.0.0", got "2.12-0-0 <3.0.0".)

Process finished with exit code 65



flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    10.0.22623.1095], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019
    16.11.10)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549623/2131651

Comment: You can remove /Users/myname/.pub-cache/ and try again. It caches some different version of package when you have multiple flutter versions or installed different versions of flutter.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer from River2202](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549623/2131651) worked for me:

> You can remove `/Users/myname/.pub-cache/` and try again. It caches
> some different version of package when you have multiple flutter
> versions or installed different versions of flutter.

Comment: Please don't copy answers. Instead, vote to [close questions as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417477/861716).

Answer (score -1):

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.